# Angular form uploading not working in Safari, working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I try upload file using angular $http.

It works properly in Chrome, and Even send a request in Safari (and have 200 response from server), but not file not uploaded to server.

I also try to use ngUpload library, but with the same result - file has not been uploaded to the server.

Source code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('userid', Users.getCurrentId());
            formData.append('avatar', myFile); // this is File() size abput 100K

            $http({
                url: AppState.getApiHost()+AppState.getApiPrefix() + '/setavatar',
                method: "POST",
                data: formData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            })
                .then(function (res) {
                    console.log('Success', res);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('Error',err)
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found an answer. The problem was with File() object was created  using File() constructor:

```
return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
```

But it not working properly with Safari. It creates File object with size equal size of file but actual file was empty. And if I try to send it after append to form - form has sent empty file (even if it looks as a not empty file).

I've replaced it to this code:

```
var the_blob = new Blob([u8arr]);
the_blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
the_blob.name = 'avatar.png'

return the_blob;
```

This is work for me